# Alternative to refbase

Tags: web-development, cms, bibtex

I am a software developer. I was asked by a friend about designing a website for its association. Here are my constraints:

- The site must be administrable even by a beginner.
- There must be a [reference management database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_management_software) for storing scientific papers (ideally compatible with [Bibtex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BibTeX) standard).

Additionally it would be cool if the following criteria were also met:

- The administration interface has a french translation.
- A nice plugin into the website for easily adding references to documents from the database

I searched a lot about this and I decided to give a try to [Spip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPIP) for the CMS and [Refbase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refbase) for the paper database. But I am struggling with a lot of problems, mostly due to the fact that last big release and documentation update for refbase was in 2008 and I am encountering mysterious bugs and since I am not a php developer myself, I can't really efficiently deal with those. I have the feeling that the provided SQL script were targeting a Mysql version that is not supported anymore. Fore example I had to replace `TYPE=MYISAM` by `ENGINE=MYISAM` in the SQL scripts to get a slightly better working POC.

Moreover I feel a bit uncomfortable about refbase's choice to accept SQL as a parameter in the url.

As a consequence, I am looking for alternatives to spip/refbase that would suit my need. Any suggestion?

**EDIT**: To answer questions in the comments:

- About the price limit, I'd rather use free or open-source software, but I would consider using a fantastic solution 20$ sub/month.
- This is for a small association with around 40 active members.
- No need for commercial use, this is a non profit association.
- Aside the reference management database, no specific feature required, I think any CMS such as Joomla or Drupal or any such should do.
- No restrictions about the server, the plan is to rent something that would suit the need. I'd rather rent a web hosting, but if the solution requires a private server, no problem. I'd rather use a Debian server though
- Users will be allowed to upload documents. The security measure I foresee is that any new user will have to get approbation from an admin prior to be able to add content.

Answer (score 0):

http://wikindx.sourceforge.net/ wikindx looks good - I have tried only the demo and not had it installed. I have used refbase and it seems to have trouble partly because it uses CGI and also runs into trouble with PHP7+.